# how to dynamically update one field in an array in mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following array in my schema:

```
{
[...]
  savedGames: [
    { name: "tutorial01", savedId: "ID0001" },
    { name: "tutorial02", savedId: "ID0001" },
    { name: "tutorial03", savedId: "ID0001" }
  ],
[...]
}
```

I would like to update the **savedId** field whenever it gets a new value. I have seen many topics using $ and arrayFilters but somehow I'm not able to figure out how to write it.

Could anyone please help me out how to write it properly?

```
[...]
const { id, savedId, name } = request.body;

await userSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, ({ "$set": { "savedGames.$.savedId": savedId }}, { arrayFilters: [{ "savedGames.name": name }]}));

return response.json("Updated.");
[...]
```

Thanks in advance!
T

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Appreciate your help!

Comment: You don't need to put `{_id: id}` in your mongoose findByIdAndUpdate query, just put `id` because that's the whole point of findByid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not very clear what's your expected output, but assuming you want to update the `savedId` field which match with values `_id` and `name` do you need something like this.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "1",
  "files.name": "name1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "files.$.savedId": "newId"
  }
})
```

With this, you will get the subdocument you want matching `_id` and `name`.
After that, the `$set` operator will update the value.

Here is a mongo playground [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qyU-NaZTgY4)

With `mongoose` you can use:

```js
var updated = await model.updateOne({
  _id: id,
  "files.name": name
},{
  $set:{
    "files.$.savedId":savedId
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, dude! This is exactly what I needed. Appreciate that you answered my question.